# Call methods from sub-classes

Tags: java, casting, polymorphism

I have a superclass named Shape, my shape class has a subclass called 2DShape and 2DShape has a subclasses named circle, square.

I have created an array of type Shape to hold these object references for the shapes

```
 Shape [] shapes = new Shape[4];

 shapes[0] =  new Circle(22, 88 , 4, 0);
 shapes[1] =  new Square(71, 96 , 0, 10);
```

My problem is that I can only call the methods from my Shape class. How can I call the methods from my Square and circle classes? both these called have a method called calcArea that I would like to call.

I get a "cannot find symbol" error when I try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {


            System.out.println(shapes[i]);
            shapes[i].calcArea();
}
```

Comment: you can use downcasting.

Comment: thanks guys, it looks like I need to cast

Answer (score 0):

You must define `calcArea()` as a method in `Shape`; it can be an abstract method, like this:

```
public abstract float calcArea();
```

and you will then need to implement that method in each subclass. It will then be available from any `Shape` subclass without casting.

Comment: this is a school exercise that I am follwing, the shape class is not allowed to have a calcArea(); method

Comment: Then you would have to cast each object to its correct type in order to call the method. It sounds like the exercise might have an error, or you don't understand something about the exercise, or there is other information that we don't have that affects things. In the loop you have above, without any way to know the class to which you need to cast each Shape, I don't see how you're going to do this reasonably. You can test each object with `instanceof` to see if it is a particular class, but that's really ugly, and I hope it wouldn't be expected in a problem illustrating polymorphism.

Comment: I've been thinking this was obvious, but perhaps it isn't -- the problem as you describe it is *exactly* what polymorphism is for -- a design that calls for each shape to have its own definition of `calcArea()`, so the superclass defines the "contract" for obtaining that area (the method signature), ensuring that every Shape subclass does have that method, and no casting will be needed. Casting is a troublesome operation; it can take significant time and throw an error that is tricky to test for, depending on the inheritance hierarchy. I don't know why an exercise would prevent you doing this.